# ¿Cómo busco en un fichero patrones que hay en otro?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo una fichero A.txt que contiene segmento para búsqueda con grep, así como otro fichero B.txt que contiene los archivos completos.

necesito que:

- lea línea a línea del fichero A.txt
- realice la búsqueda en el fichero B.txt
- se guarde en un nuevo fichero C.txt

Formato del fichero A.txt

```
01-0026
01-0037
01-0423
```

Formato del fichero B.txt

```
01-0020-01L.S202201
01-0026-43L.S202201
01-0032-01L.S202201
01-0037-30L.S202201
01-0048-12L.S202201
01-0108-04L.S202201
01-0128-07L.S202201
01-0423-00L.S202201
```

Estaba realizandolo de esta manera

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  grep "$line" B.txt
done < A.txt > C.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grep tiene la opción `-f` exactamente para esto: lee los patrones de un fichero:

```
grep -f fichero_patrones fichero
```

En tu caso, esto da:

```
$ grep -f a b
01-0026-43L.S202201
01-0037-30L.S202201
01-0423-00L.S202201
```

Para guardarlo en un fichero "c", simplemente redirige la salida: `grep -f a b > c`.

Como siempre, puedes luego complicar la cosa usando otras opciones de Grep o subir el nivel y abrazar algo de Awk.

Answer (score 2):

Te adjunto un posible solución. Agregué una comprobación inicial opcional para que al ejecutar el script borre `C.txt`. Esto para evitar errores ya que si corres el script dos veces obtendrás resultados duplicados en `C.txt`.

En general, para cada línea en `A.txt` ejecutas `grep $line B.txt` y si el resultado no es nulo lo agregas a `C.txt`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f "C.txt" ]; then  # Si el archivo existe
   rm C.txt  # Se elimina el archivo
fi

for line in $(<A.txt); # Lee línea por línea
do
    result=$(grep "$line" B.txt) # Busca en B.txt la línea leída
  [ -z "$result" ] || echo $result >> C.txt # Si no está vacía, la agrega a C.txt
done
```

El fichero `C.txt` que se crea, para los archivos `A.txt` y `B.txt` que adjuntas en tu pregunta es:

```
01-0026-43L.S202201
01-0037-30L.S202201
01-0423-00L.S202201
```

Comment: Vote tu respuesta a favor por ser atrevida, pero te recomiendo des una rapidísima explicación sobre  `$(<A.txt)`, y las desventajas de usar una y otra y otra vez `grep`.

Comment: @Cuauhtli la verdad no recordaba la opcion  -f de grep cuando resolvi la pregunta . La respuesta aceptada es por mucho mas optima ya que recorrerá el archivo destino una sola vez, mientras yo lo recorreré la cantidad de líneas que tenga A. No obstante no borré mi respuesta para que el OP vea otra posible via (mas parecida a la que el estaba planteando) y por si quiere ejecutar mas de un comando por línea, lo pueda hacer dentro del for. Gracias por tu comentario. Ten en cuenta que yo fui el primero que respondi, si hubiera estado la excelente respuesta que dio fedorqui no hubiera respondido.

Comment: Ni la borres! Es buena para los que quieran aprender toda la caja de monerías que trae bash. Por lo general, los que somos adictos a Bash, no tenemos taaaaantos conflictos con lo "optimo", sino con lo que use más Bash :')
De hecho, mi sugerencia va en el sentido de que expliques una que otra cosita más sobre Bash que hay en tu respuesta.

Comment: Muy interesante la conversación con @Cuauhtli :) Lo mismo sería más seguro usar `while IFS= read -r patron; do grep "$patron" B.txt; done < A.txt`. Es decir, usar la sintaxis `< fichero` para inyectar cada una de las líneas de A.